# cocoa core data app crashes on insert when use one to one relationship

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have simple cocoa app with 2 entities. They have one to one relationship between them.

In my only window, I have 2 NSTableViews, one display the customer and in another his address. If I change the relationship between the 2 entities in one to many, then everything in my app works (add, edit, delete).

However, if I change the relationship between the 2 entities in one to one, I can insert the customer, but when I attempt to insert record in the second NSTableView (address) app crashes with following error:

**2015-10-09 03:50:28.357 TwoEntitiesRecord[1793:56879] -[__NSSetM managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000040f90
2015-10-09 03:50:28.357 TwoEntitiesRecord[1793:56879] -[__NSSetM managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000040f90
2015-10-09 03:50:28.361 TwoEntitiesRecord[1793:56879] (**

I am not posting any code for the app, since I didn't write one. It is all done trough binding.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incorrect binding.  As you can tell from the error message, you are asking an NSSet for its managedObjectContext.  An NSSet does not have a managed object context.

So, look at your bindings.  One of them is probably bound to the property that represents a relationship, as that would be an instance of NSSet.  Your binding is probably asking it for the MOC.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that someone has same issue: In one of my array controllers, the one for the address, in array controller attribute inspector I had unchecked auto rearrange content checkbox.

Honestly I have no idea why after I checked this checkbox app suddenly stop crashing on insert, but that was the solution for my problem.